# Possible to create an abstract property?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a property that looks like this in a Child class:

```js
formModel = {
    motive: 0,
    coop: 0,
    leadership: 0,
    teamwork: 0,
    community: 0,
    professional: 0,
    role_model: 0,
    supportive: 0,
    problem_solving: 0
};
```

But in other child classes, this property is different.

```js
formModel = {
    motive: 0,
    coop: 0,
    leadership: 0,
    teamwork: 0,
    community: 0,
    professional: 0,
    communication: 0,
    respect: 0,
    morale: 0,
    role_model: 0,
    supp_enviro: 0
};
```

The order of the attributes changes and the names change too.

I want to declare an `abstract` version of this property in its Parent class. Is this possible? I'm having no such luck with `public abstract formModel: Object;` in the parent.

Edit:

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
vendor.bundle.js:40839 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    at syntaxError (vendor.bundle.js:40839)
    at vendor.bundle.js:54719
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.bundle.js:54717)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (vendor.bundle.js:66103)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.bundle.js:66076)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.bundle.js:66005)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (vendor.bundle.js:71695)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (vendor.bundle.js:71681)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:1339)
```

I noticed that I only get this error if I add the following method to my parent class, instead of the child class:

```ts
public handleRadioButtonChanges(event: Event): void {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no such luck"?  Is the parent class abstract?

Comment: In the parent class, I've put `public abstract formModel: Object;` and I get errors. It doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: Is the parent class `abstract` or not?  Can you post code with some errors?

Comment: The parent class is `abstract`, yes. I've already posted the relevant code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have not posted [enough code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem.  I can create an abstract parent class with the abstract property you mention, and I get no errors.  What errors do you get, and where do you get them?

Comment: How are you creating the abstract property? I'll post the error then.

Comment: @jcalz I've added the error and more code.

Comment: you don't have to define the event to be of type `Event` explicitly if you are calling this method from template in response to an event like this `handleRadioButtonChanges($event)`. It could be of a different type within the method definition, like a `string` or `boolean` or likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface for it, if you are only concerned about its type.

```
export interface FormModel {
 motive: number;
 coop: number;
 leadership: number;
 teamwork: number;
 community: number;
 professional: number;
 role_model: number;
 supportive: number;
 problem_solving: number;
}
```

Then in child you could simply declare this `formModel` of the type `FormModel` defined in the parent (you also have to import this interface in the child component.ts file).

```
import { FormModel } from 'app/<Interface's location>';

formModel: FormModel;
```

**EDIT**

You could make them optional by adding `?` to its declaration like `motive?: number;`, if that helps. So add this to attributes you feel are optional. Or simply only declare the properties that you think are present always (without optional) and then add a dynamic property like this.

```
export interface FormModel {
 motive: number;
 coop: number;
 leadership: number;
 teamwork: number;
 community: number;
 professional: number;
 role_model: number;
 supportive: number;
 problem_solving: number;
 [key: string]: any; // <-- leaving room for optional extra properties
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the `formModel` property varies in the number of attributes. I wanted to make it generic in the parent class so that I could move more logic into it instead of handling it in the component.

Comment: you could make them optional by adding `?` to its declaration like `motive?: number;`, if that helps. See my updated answer

Comment: With regard to your update, the order of the attributes doesn't matter. But the names do matter. So what is it that you know 'for sure' about this object `formModel` and its properties when you define it in the parent class? If you have a list of properties that you know for sure it will have in each of it's instantiation, then we could start with that. At least, you should know something about this object which makes you define it in the parent as a certain type. If you don't know anything about it to begin with we could simply declare it with a dynamic key. Please clarify on this first?

Comment: I didn't realize the names matter. That fixed my issues. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't it get resolved? Do you have further issues with it?

Comment: Some guy above said he was able to make the property abstract. If he/she doesn't come through, then you get it.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a common way to declare Object types: `public abstract formModel: Object;`. Do this instead if that's the way you wanna go with (this comment is purely based on the syntax used in this line, nothing to do with your answer conceptually): `public abstract formModel: any;`

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the question as stated is emphatically **yes**, you can create abstract properties.  I can do the following with no errors:

```
// what are the restrictions on FormModel? 
// See [@amal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328720/2887218) 
// for discussion about this
interface FormModel {
  [key: string]: number;
}

abstract class Parent {
  public abstract formModel: FormModel;  
  public handleRadioButtonChanges(event: Event): void {
    console.log("test");
}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  formModel = {
    motive: 0,
    coop: 0,
    leadership: 0,
    teamwork: 0,
    community: 0,
    professional: 0,
    role_model: 0,
    supportive: 0,
    problem_solving: 0
  };
}

class AnotherChild extends Parent {
  formModel = {
    motive: 0,
    coop: 0,
    leadership: 0,
    teamwork: 0,
    community: 0,
    professional: 0,
    communication: 0,
    respect: 0,
    morale: 0,
    role_model: 0,
    supp_enviro: 0
  };
}
```

---

However, the error you're getting seems to be something specific to webpack, and I don't know what is causing it.  When I compile with tsc there's no difference between the emitted JavaScript made with or without the `public abstract formModel: FormModel;` line.  It's just type information, which tends not to find its way into JavaScript.  You might need to give more info about your environment so someone can reproduce.

In any case, the problem you're having probably has very little to do with abstract properties per se, except that it is being exposed when you add that property to the parent class. Perhaps [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831) is relevant?  Or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794233)?  I really don't know since I don't have any webpack expertise.

Comment: Just to point out, this one basically conveys the same idea I mentioned in my answer to use interfaces to define types. Define known properties if they are 'required' in all instantiations of this type, if not use a dynamic key! like `[key: string]: number;` or `[key: string]: any;` (if you are unsure of the type to be a `number`)

Comment: Ah. I'm realizing now the issue might be where I'm placing a certain function. You're right though; the issue has nothing to do with abstract properties.

Comment: @amal sure, I do mention a type definition for `FormModel` but that's neither the apparent point of the question (which is if abstract properties are possible... answer: yes), nor the actual problem @Nxt3 is having (which has something to do with webpack or the interplay between TypeScript and webpack).  Edit: mentioned your answer in my post now, if that helps :-)